# Select a value from one of the tables if a value equels a value from the other table

Tags: php, mysql

There are two mysql tables `games_server` and `orders_order`. I need to select value called `full_address` from the first table only if value `id` from this table equals to the value `server_id` of the second table `orders_order`.

But not just any value. It has to be `WHERE service_type = 'be_first' AND status = 'running'`

I've read possible solutions here and tried something like that:

```
SELECT server_address
FROM games_server
WHERE id IN
    SELECT server_id
    FROM orders_order
    WHERE service_type = 'be_first'
      AND status = 'running'
ORDER BY updated DESC
```

but it didn't work. I'm not good with mysql. Please help out.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.thing you want to select
  FROM table you want to select from AS a
  JOIN the other table AS b
    ON b.some column = a.some column
 WHERE some criterion is met
   AND another criterion is met
```

Comment: Probably an idea to read a book or basic tutorial before proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
mysql_query("SELECT a.full_address FROM games_server AS a JOIN orders_order AS b ON b.server_id = a.id WHERE service_type = 'be_first' AND status = 'running'");
```

Then to add order by:

```
mysql_query("SELECT a.full_address FROM games_server AS a JOIN orders_order AS b ON b.server_id = a.id WHERE service_type = 'be_first' AND status = 'running' ORDER BY column_name");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
mysql_query("SELECT a.'full_address' FROM 'games_server' AS 'a' JOIN 'orders_order' AS 'b' ON b.'server_id' = a.'id' WHERE service_type = 'be_first' AND status = 'running');
```

is the code you have atm and I'm pretty sure it throws an error. Try removing the `AS` keyword so that it looks like this:

```
mysql_query("SELECT a.'full_address' FROM 'games_server' a JOIN 'orders_order' b ON b.'server_id' = a.'id' WHERE service_type = 'be_first' AND status = 'running');
```

Try reading the following article on the mysql website: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-alias.html